# QODBC Performance Optimizations

Tags: sql, odbc, quickbooks

I'm working with an 800MB QuickBook file on an Enterprise install and QODBC queries take several minutes if they complete at all.

I've read [posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584512/qodbc-select-taking-15-minutes-to-return-results/27598224#27598224) on the topic as well as Flexquarters' KB, but am specifically seeking advice on what performance improvements can be expected with these options or combination of for a weekly reporting system that only needs the last year's transactions (read only).

1. Truncating the database to the past year
2. Using OpenSync to export to a SQL database
3. Exporting a subset of the tables using OpenSync

Also, does OpenSync maintain QODBC's data model? Can anyone report their experiences if that's the best option, as QODBC is only translating requests to XML so I'm not sure if any amount of optimization for it will be enough.

Answer (score 2):

**Performance**

I would suggest to

1)  to enable QODBC status panel via QODBC Setup Screen->Message Window->Select "Display Driver Status" and "Display optimizer Status" options.

2) execute below command on VB Demo

```
SP_OPTIMIZEFULLSYNC ALL
```

3) Close all the application(s)

4) Connect with your application and run any query.
You should see a performance improvement.

The sp_optimizefullsync will Optimize all tables from scratch.

The sp_optimizeupdatesync  will keep the existing Optimizer as it is and add all the delta change your Optimizer file so that it is up to date.

> that only needs the last year's transactions (read only).

On the QODBC Setup Screen, Optimizer, You may set one of the following options

The end of last month option is a great speed boost for running last month or last year’s queries. It does not need to synchronize again to get the data.

OR

The last time I pressed one of the load data buttons option allows you to control the synchronized timing. Synchronizing only occurs when you manually run it by pressing the Load Updated Data in the QODBC setup screen.

Those options will stop optimizer to be sync with QuickBooks for the selected time. (latest changes will not be brought).  AS QODBC will not sync the data from its last sync, you should get performance again.

You can manually sync the Optimizer using:

```
SP_OPTIMIZEUPDATESYNC ALL
```

Refer : http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2358/48/how-to-setup-qodbc-optimizer-and-where-are-the-optimizer-options

**To sync to SQL Server.**

You can make use of QRemote, Create a Linked Server.
http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2666/0/how-to-create-link-server-with-ms-sql-200520082012-32-bit-using-qodbc-onlineqremote

Write SQL Script to import data
e.g.

```
drop table sqlCustomer
go
SELECT * INTO sqlCustomer  FROM qodbc...customer;
```

Every Week run below command so that your optimizer file is up to date:

```
SP_OPTIMIZEUPDATESYNC ALL
```

Comment: How can we run SP_OPTIMIZEUPDATESYNC ALL using qodbc online SQL linked server?